# How to declare a constant in C#/.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, constants

I have the following code:

```
public class iSito
{
    public const string myVar = "5262";

    public iSito()
    {

    }
}
```

Now, if from any context (in my case, a .ascx.cs) I try to use iSito.myVar, I can't get any value.

Why?

Comment: Could you post a sample of the code in your .ascx.cs file?  Also what specifically do you mean by "I can't get any value"?

Comment: Can you give some more info ?  Do you have a compile error ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is the iSito class in another DLL / assembly ?  If so, have you rebuild the DLL and have you rebuild the application that consumes the DLL ?

A const value is written as a literal in the IL when you compile the client application.  If you change the const, you'll have to rebuild the client app.

What happens if you change the const to be readonly ?  (Just for testing purposes).

Comment: When you declare the variable to be readonly, you do not have to rebuild the client app when you change the value of that variable.

Comment: @markzzz Good point about the potential need of a rebuild. 
It's often encouraged to use static readonly when the value is public and only use const when internal or private

Answer (score 11):

Your example is correct and should work  - consts are automatically static, so you can access the field as `iSito.myVar` - make sure you qualify with the full namespace, same as needed to access the class (or add an appropriate using statement).

Answer (score 0):

iSito.myVar works. I tried it.

Comment: Not that helpful you could suggest possible reasons why it might not work for OP. (Such as missing using directive)

Comment: OK, I just wanted to justify the fact that this syntax MUST work.